# Can you track a smoke simulation's velocity and use it to drive the location of a noise texture?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm making a campfire and I'm wondering if it's possible to utilize a smoke simulation's velocity to drive the location of a noise texture. I'm trying to move the noise texture so it matches the speed of the fire. Can you track that sort of thing? Thanks in advance.